# understanding concept to get mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I can handle mysql data well using this approach:

```
        $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root', 'root');
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                return;
        }
        $select1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from review_words");

        $record =  @mysqli_fetch_assoc($select1);
        echo $record['noun'];
```

I hope it's standard way.

Currently I came accross one new way to do same:

```
    $this->db = new Database($config->getDbHost(), $config->getDbUsername(), $config->getDbPassword(), $config->getDbName());
    $this->table = array
    (
        'users'=>$this->table_prefix.'user_t', 
        'accounts' => $this->table_prefix.'accounts_t'
    )
    function getT($name)
    {
          return $this->table[$name];
    }
    $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM ".$this->getT('accounts'));
```

If table `accounts` has values `name`, `id`. How can get access of it?

**UPDATE**

```
function validateRequest($key)
{    
    $this->db->select("SELECT user_id FROM ".$this->getT('accounts')."where account_key = '".$key."'");
    $data = $this->db->execute();
    $userid = $data['user_id'];

    $this->db->select("SELECT user_status FROM ".$this->getT('users')."where user_id = '".$userid."'");
    $data = $this->db->execute();
    $userstatus = $data['user_status'];     
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what the values name and id have to do with your question? Do you want to know why or how the second code works? If you are wondering how to access the values from the $this->db (Database Class) you will have to have a look into the class and see what methods are provided.

Comment: @DaveCartwright: I checked class, I did not get any referece for mysqli class access. I appreciate if you can give clue for how to execute above query using mysqli

Comment: Well the Database class seems to be a wrapper to handle a different logic. It's really difficult to post an answer without knowing how the  Database class really looks like. I of course can rewrite the later functionality with the code of your first example?

Comment: The second method is not in any way a default class or method of PHP, it's some custom code that we have no idea about. It doesn't even make much sense as is without context. We cannot answer your question.

Comment: @DaveCartwright: I appreciate if you can do it for first example

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Only difference between your code and other one is that other code was designed to handle table prefixes without need to rewrite queries every time you need change prefixes for tables. Thanks to prefixes you can run 2 instances of page from one DB (every instance will have own tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a brief example of your code put into a small class wrapper. For simplicity I'm not checking for bad user input, though this should normally always be done.

**This example is for testing purposes and could of course be made a lot nicer ;-).**

I also haven't had the opportunity to test this code so please excuse me if there are any errors.
This code is Expecting your database has two tables "tb_users" and "tb_accounts".

The Database wrapper:

```
class Database {

    public $db; 
    private $sql;   

    public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $database) {

        $this->db = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

        /* check connection */
        if ($this->db->connect_errno) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $this->db->connect_errno . ") " . $this->db->connect_error, 1);
        }
    }

    public function select($table, $cols) {

            $colsearch = (is_array($cols)) ? implode(", ", $cols) : $cols;
            $sql = "SELECT " . $colsearch . " from " . $table;
    }

    public function execute() {
        if (! is_null($this->sql)) {
            $rs = $this->db->query($this->sql);

            if($rs === false) {
                throw new Exception('Problematic SQL: ' . $this->sql . ' Error: ' . $this->db->error, 1);
            } else {
                return $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            }

        } else {
            return null;
        }   
    }
}
```

The Model wrapper:

```
class MyModel {

    private $tbl_prefix = "tb_";

    private $tables;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->tables = array(
            "users" => $this->tbl_prefix . "users",
            "accounts" => $this->tbl_prefix . "accounts"
        );
    }

    public function getTableByName($name) {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->tables)) {
            return $this->tables[$name];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Executing the code:

```
$myDatabase = new Database('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root', 'root');

$myModel = new MyModel();

$myDatabase->select($myModel->getTableByName("users"), array(
    "name",
    "id"
));

$data = $myDatabase->execute();

foreach ($data as $item) {
    print_r($item);
}
```

Hope this helps you a little.

Comment: I updated the code at the end, is that code snippet is correct?

Comment: I wrote the code I supplied in my answer to provide you with an example, It has nothing to do with the second part of code you posted (except for some logic). Nobody here will be able to answer your question in relation to the Database class you posted earlier because nobody here can know what functions exist in that class. Or are you asking this in relation to my examples?

Comment: I invested some time to write up this answer after you explicitly asked that I use the code out of your first code block and write a example incorporating the logic of the second block. A short answer if it helped you solve your problem or if there is something else you need would be nice? Thank you.